# SAPUI 5 fileuploder controller function getFocusDomRef not working sometime

Tags: javascript, file-upload, sapui5

This seems to be weird error. :)

I am using the SAPIU5 fileuploder controller, it seems to be working fine. But sometimes the function getFocusDomRef is not able to fetch the parameters.

One more strange behaviour is that, it is working in Mac (chrome) without any issues but with Windows (chrome) it fails sometimes.

Using chrome Version 70.0.3538.102

Below is the code snippet:

```
 <u:FileUploader id="fileUploader" name="myFileUpload" fileType="csv" uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete" typeMissmatch="checkTypeMissmatch" fileAllowed="fileTypeAllowed" />
```

Controller:

```
handleUploadComplete() =>
     var loFileUploader = sap.ui.getCore().byId("fileUploader");
            loFileUploader.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
            var Title = sap.ui.getCore().byId("importCollectionTitle").getValue();

            var domRefFile = loFileUploader.getFocusDomRef(); //The Buggy boy

            var file = domRefFile.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(evt) {

            var postXMLUploadFile = evt.target.result.trim().replace(/\r/g, "");
            var rows = postXMLUploadFile.split("\n");

           //Import CSV file data

        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this functionality I've always used a button to get the files and using `getFocusDomRef()` never had a problem. You should also use [`FileReader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the content of the files asynchronously with [`FileReader.readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText)
 after the download is actually finished.

Use the [`FileReader.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) property that contains an event handler executed when the load event is fired.

Using a button in your XML view:

```
<u:FileUploader id="idfileUploader" sameFilenameAllowed="false" buttonText="" fileType="CSV" placeholder="Choose a CSV file"/>
<Button text="Upload" press="onUpload" id="__uploadButton" tooltip="Upload CSV File"/>
```

In the controller:

```
    onUpload: function() {
        //get file from uploader
        var domRef = this.getView().byId("idfileUploader").getFocusDomRef();
        var oFile = domRef.files[0];
        if (oFile && window.FileReader) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            //onload function
            reader.onload = function(evt) {
                //file string
                var strCSV = evt.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsText(oFile);
        } else {
            //File Reader not supported
            alert("Please Upload a CSV File!");
        }
    },
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am using a button for upload also. ( May be that was 'also' the error ) and as you pointed out i have removed the "uploadComplete" from the fileuploader.
Also i am using the fileupload.upload() ( editing my question ).
As of now i did not face the issue again. :)

Comment: Check version SAPUI5